# Use the result of checked method inside conditional statement

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement and `Authorization` module, because currently the authorization logic for a certain resource is separated on two or three different places and even though I'm not sure this is the best approach, at least I think it will provide some encapsulation.

Since I'm checking for several different things

1. Does the user have the right role
2. Is the resources in the right state to process the required action
3. Do the user has the right to perform the required action on this particular resource

So as you can see, there are several checks, I'm not pretending to be completely correct here, but this is pretty close to the real case, so I've decided to use something like a [Result Object](https://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/result-objects-errors-without-exceptions/) even though it's actually not an object but a `struct` and I'm not using Gem but pretty simple custom implementation.

So part of my `Authorization` module is this:

```
module Authorization
  Result = Struct.new(:successfull?, :error)

  extend self

  def read(user, resource, message: 'Permission denied')
    can_read =
      [
        condition1,
        condition2,
        condition3
      ]

    return Result.new(can_read.any?, can_read.any? ? nil : message))
  end
```

However within this `Authorization` module I have a lot of methods and some of them check `read` internally like so:

```
def assign(user, resource, message: 'Permission denied')
  return read(user, resource) unless read(user, resource).successfull?

  Result.new(true, nil)
end
```

So my main question is how to avoid this double call to `read(user, resource)`. I guess one option would be to just call it before the check like:

```
result = read(user, resource)
return result unless result.successfull?
```

However I'm pretty new to `Ruby` and I suspect that maybe there is more ruby-like way to do this. Just to inline it somehow by assigning the result from `read` inside the condition check...However this is just wild guess.

And one more question, that came up while I was writing this. Currently if I want to send `nil` for message when the authorization passes I'm doing this:

```
return Result.new(can_read.any?, can_read.any? ? nil : message))
```

Because `message unless can_read.any?` is throwing and error even though I thought it would default to `nil`. So again, is there some more ruby-like way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part can be written with [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-yield_self):

```
def assign(user, resource, message: 'Permission denied')
  read(user, resource).yield_self do |res|
    res.successful? ? Result.new(true, nil) : res
  end
end
```

`successfull?` -> `successful?` for English reasons. I am not convinced this is more readable than using a local variable though. Alternatively:

```
(res = read(user, resource)).successful? ? Result.new(true, nil) : res
```

As for your second question, you'll need more parentheses

```
Result.new(can_read.any?, (message if can_read.none?))
```

the `return` is not needed.

I would also advise you to slow down with all the `unless`es, try to swap your conditions to `if` whenever possible -- I find it quite useful to make `Result` a class and define a `failed?` method for it. Actually, I'd consider this:

```
class Result
  def initialize(error)
    @error = error
  end

  def successful?
    @error.nil?
  end

  def failed?
    !successful?
  end
end
```

That depends on how complicated your `Result` gets, but for the use case shown, it would be a little cleaner imho.

Comment: Thanks, those were the answers I was looking for. However if you have the time, I would like to ask you two a question. I'm in serious doubt about this `Authorization` module. Even though it encapsulates logic which now can be found across 3 different modules, I feel forced to do most of the authorization inside the action calls, rather than the `before_action` filter. Have you seen something like this, do you think it's a viable idea and do you think it could be done better?

Comment: I've done something similar in the past, as I prefer controllers to be explicitly in charge of authorization, instead of models (looking at `cancancancan` here). I found that I had to go outside of `before_filter` only in some very specific cases, but my `Authorization` was a class that was being initialized with some context of controller actions (`current_user`, `id` parameters, etc.). Worked well for me.